# System.arraycopy Chopping Off Bytes

Tags: java, sockets

I'm using the below code to read data from a connected socket and the data I'm receiving in the buffer variable after I execute the System.arraycopy(tempBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, byteRead) code is of length 41 bytes.  The sending system is sending 43 bytes.  Anyone know why arraycopy is chopping off the other bytes?

```
public class BluetoothClientSocket{
     private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

          private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
          private final InputStream mmInStream;
          private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

         public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
               mmSocket = socket;
               InputStream tmpIn = null;
               OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //handle exception logic
            }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
          }

         public void run(){
             byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[1024];
             byte[] buffer = null;
             int byteRead;

             while (true) {
                try {
                        InputStream itStrm = mmInStream;
                        byteRead = mmInStream.read(tempBuffer);
                        if(byteRead > 0){
                             buffer = new byte[byteRead];
                             System.arraycopy(tempBuffer, 0, buffer, 0, byteRead);
                        }
                   }
                   catch(Exception ex){
                       //handle exception logic
                   }
              }
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The sending system is sending 43 bytes.

That doesn't mean you're *receiving* all 43 bytes in a single call to `read`.

> Anyone know why arraycopy is chopping off the other bytes?

It's not. I suspect you'll find that `byteRead` is 41, which means the "problem" occurs before `arraycopy` gets involved.

I'd expect you to get the remaining two bytes (and possibly more data, if the other end has sent any more) on the next call to `read`.

Either that or your code is wrong on the other end, and you're only sending 41 bytes to start with.

Comment: would you recommend using a DataInputStream and its readFully method help ensure that all bytes are read?

Comment: It looks like you were correct, the two missing bytes contain the CRC.  I guess that got stripped off somewhere along the way.